# Formula for negative polylogarithms

Tags: nt.number-theory, polylogarithms

> **Theorem**. We have that $\displaystyle \underbrace{x\left(\dfrac{d}{dx}\left(\cdots x \left(\dfrac{d}{dx} \left( \dfrac{x}{1-x}\right)\right)\cdots\right)\right)}_{\text{$x \frac{d}{dx}$ $m$ times}}=\dfrac{1}{(1-x)^{m+1}}\sum_{k=0}^{m-1} A(m,k) x^{m-k}$ where $A(a,k)$ are the Eulerian numbers and $m$ is a nonnegative integer.

I am looking at the polylogarithm function $\operatorname{Li}_{-s}(z) = \displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{z^k}{k^{-s}}$ and trying to find its formula for nonnegative integers $s$. Since it is easily verified that

$$\displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}k^m x^k =\underbrace{x\left(\dfrac{d}{dx}\left(\cdots x \left(\dfrac{d}{dx} \left( \dfrac{x}{1-x}\right)\right)\cdots\right)\right)}_{\text{$x \frac{d}{dx}$ $m$ times}},$$ the result follows from this. I have noticed that the change of variables $x = e^t$ gives us $$\underbrace{x\left(\dfrac{d}{dx}\left(\cdots x \left(\dfrac{d}{dx} \left( \dfrac{x}{1-x}\right)\right)\cdots\right)\right)}_{\text{$x \frac{d}{dx}$ $m$ times}} =  \dfrac{d^m}{dt^m}\left(\dfrac{1}{1-e^t} \right),$$ but I am wondering how to utilize this to prove the theorem.

Comment: Does this help?  http://www.landsburg.com/query.pdf

Answer (score 1):

It is known that $Li_{-n}(x)$ is just

$$\sum_{k=0}^nk!S(n+1,k+1)(\frac{x}{1-x})^{k+1}$$

see,  L. Lewin, Polylogarithms and associated functions,
North Holland,1981

and https://web.williams.edu/Mathematics/sjmiller/public_html/math/papers/PolyLogIdentity01.pdf

Moreover,

Negative polylogarithm correspounds to Poly-Bernoulli numbers at negative integers

see theorem 1 here http://www2.math.kyushu-u.ac.jp/~mkaneko/papers/44poly-bernoulli_numbers.pdf

Comment: I am looking for a way to prove my theorem and not prove the polylogarithm result directly using poly-bernoulli numbers. In the latter case we would still have the Stirling numbers of the second kind as coefficients, but it might be possible to show it is equal by using the formula you have.

Comment: see http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1130184/polylogarithms-of-negative-integer-order

Comment: I think the result is more easily proved with a intermediate step such as my theorem above.

Comment: This type of questions are suitable for stack.mathexchange and not for mathoverflow. It is seems to be exersise in BA level